# What is the proper way to validate a physical commercial/residential address?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Currently, I limit an address to 100 characters with no rules about what it must be composed of. Punctuation, digits, letters; all are welcome.

I use `strip_tags` upon saving the address to my database (prepared statements). I use `$this->escape()` (Zend Framework) when echoing it to a page.

I don't want to go crazy, but I think that I need to be a little more restrictive. What am I missing?

Comment: Drive there and see if it exists.

Comment: Why `strip_tags()` before inserting it into the database? Just escape the special characters dependent on output context.

Comment: I don't know of any, but you might want to find a library that standardizes address inputs

Comment: @alex: The sooner I can stop malicious input, the better

Comment: Probably you can look up for a particular address with google maps API, if it provides such feature. Not confident in it though.

Comment: @mazzzzz: I'm not concerned about standardization (i.e. ensuring that each piece is in its correct spot). I just don't want a user to be able to enter a huge block of nonsense into my database.

Comment: 100 characters, no tags seems like no one's gonna inject code or even visual walls of text.

Comment: When users enter nonsense into your address fields, they're telling you something. What do you think they're telling you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are US addresses, you should use the United States Postal Service's APIs to look up and standardize addresses.

http://www.usps.com/webtools/

Comment: +1 for referring to the authority. For low volume requirements, you can manually check addresses with their ZIP code lookup. http://zip4.usps.com/zip4/welcome.jsp  But in my experience, the USPS lags local government in address changes. Not by a lot, but that makes a difference to some apps.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Dan's answer, I would submit that the best solution for you is to perform a simple request to an address validation service, such as [SmartyStreets' LiveAddress](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/) (it's totally free and uses official USPS data). I actually work for SmartyStreets, so I've been through these hoops time and time again.

I read the comments on your question, and even though it doesn't appear to be a matter of standardizing the address, ... it really is in the end. Users can enter bad data -- and if they do it on purpose, that *does* tell you something right there, as Catcall mentioned -- and you want to make sure it is correct and complete. CASS-Certified vendors can provide this service, and I think the easiest/most affordable one you'll find is LiveAddress.

There's no regular expression which will do this, and even the USPS API has its major drawbacks/limitations, despite being the authority (for example, it's not always clear on its deliverability).

When you verify any input, even an address, for validity, it also builds the trust of your users so that they know you care about their interactions with you.